# Flask, dynamically generate link to file

Tags: python, flask

How can I dynamically generate link to files using flask? Here is my sample code but it's not working when I click on the link. all the file in the directory are text files, so the browser can open them without downloading anything.

```
{% for x, y in links %}
<tr>
     <td><a href="{{y}}">{{x}}</a></td>
     <td><a href="{{y}}">{{y}}</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}

path = 'path/directory'
if request.method == 'GET':
# a is the date last modified, b is the file path
    link = [(a, b) for a, b in get_files_sorted(path)]
    return render_template('file_structure.html', links=link)
if request.method == 'POST':
    #open the text file that was clicked on
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your files are in your static directory you can do something like this:

`<td><a href="{{ url_for('static', filename=y) }}">{{x}}</a></td>`

or

`<td><a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='path/directory/%s' % (y)) ) }}">{{x}}</a></td>`